# Complexity of breaking Vigenère cipher

Tags: encryption, cryptography, time-complexity, caesar-cipher, vigenere

So I want to know what is the time complexity of deciphering a text of n words encrypted bt Vigenère.

Vigenère is just applying different Caesar shifts for each letter.
I know that for a Caesar Cipher it is just O(n) Because we simply try all different 25 shifts. But what about Vigenère?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breaking Ceasar's shift is `O(1)`, not `O(n)`. The size of the alphabet is constant. You only need to decode a short stretch of the ciphertext under a given key to know if you are on track.

For Vigenere's cipher you have sequence of repeating shifts. The brute-force way to break it without statistical analysis depends on the key space, which is `O(26^k)` for a key of length `k`. Because statistical analysis is highly effective on Vigenere's cipher, its actual strength is much lower than would be suggested by this time bound.

Comment: How about this implementation of the Caesar cipher here --> https://github.com/a-p-jo/C5/blob/master/C5.c